# JavaScript getting date string as 11pm on the day before

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following input field:
In my web app I have -

`string date - 06/05/2018`

And this JS code:

```
var d = "06/05/2018".split("/");
var date = new Date(d[2] + "-" + d[1] + "/" + d[0]).getTime();
console.log(date)
```

This returns `1525561200000` which if I put that into [epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) gives me...

`Saturday, May 5, 2018 11:00:00 PM`

This then screws up with my filtering system - date ranges because if I select the minimum date to be `06/05/2018` with the input field:

```
var d = $('#min').val()
var date = new Date(d).getTime();
console.log(date)
```

[image: input field]

It is returning `1525564800000` which comes to `Sunday, May 6, 2018 12:00:00 AM`

How do I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that the timezones you are working with are the same. Epochconverter shows you two timezones

Comment: You're confusing Month/Day and Day/Month. Note that the output isn't just the 6th, it's **May** 6.

Comment: I think you must to delete ".getTime()" in second line?! Is that you want?

Comment: @SerhatMERCAN That gives the actual ms.

Comment: @Luca I think it's something to do with the timezones but how is that set in JS?

Comment: @AhmedFasih, I am aware. I am using it in Day/Month. I'm from the UK :)

Comment: @Luca the JS still gives two different results for `.getTime()` when I am using the same date. The only difference is one is entered manually and one is entered via a date input field.

Comment: @Shiv *Entered via a date input field*. As in, your passing the value of the date input directly to the `Date` constructor? That value is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` while the string you're passing in manually has the format `YYYY-MM/DD`. I've never seen that date format, but it does indeed seem to result in different date objects. It's generally not a good idea to create date objects from a string, as it's not standardized and differs between browsers. I suggest you parse the numbers and pass them to the date constructor in that way instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could write an entire thesis on how problematic and difficult it is to work with dates in Javascript and how to avoid pitfalls and weird bugs, but in the end your specific problem comes down to a simple typo.
The string you're parsing manually and passing to the `Date` constructor looks like this:

`2018-05/06`

You've mistakenly used a `/` instead of a `-` as the second delimiter when concatenating the string. For some reason, the browser then creates the date object as *midnight 2018-05-06* **local time**. When passing in the string in the standard format (which is what happens when taking it from the date input), i.e. `2018-05-06`, the date object gets created as *midnight 2018-05-06* **UTC time**.

So, in short, your problem can be solved by replacing the `"/"` with `"-"` in your string concatenation and the two dates should be the same.

However, I should point out that passing a string to the `Date` constructor is unreliable since the result is not standardized and may differ between browsers (which is also why it behaves so unpredictable and seemingly illogical in this case). It's a better idea to pass numbers instead since the specification dictates the result of that. You're already halfway there since you've split the date string into its components. Try this:

```
var date = new Date(
  Number(d[2]), 
  Number(d[1]) - 1, // Subtracting 1 from month since it's base 0 
  Number(d[0])
).getTime();
```

*(Technically, we don't even need to explicitly convert to `Number` since the `Date` constructor expects all arguments to be numbers when there's more than one argument and will convert whatever it gets into numbers internally)*

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Using your technique and it's working on different browsers now as well! :D